# How does Newton's third law work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

This law states that to each action there is an opposite and equal reaction. and I understand that this is the law that Rocket thrusters are built on. they use the combustion of fuel to push out hot exhaust gas in huge quantities and acceleration, and the gas in turn will push the rocket in the opposite direction.
So theoretically if we let's say have a 1/2 pound beach ball resting on a 100 pound metal bowling ball and we quickly pull the bowling ball to the right giving it a great amount of acceleration (similar to the exhaust gas). the ball should in turn provide a force in the opposite direction that is equal to force we applied on it, and should cause the beach ball to move to the left. But that does not happen. if we do this, the beach ball would simply either stay at rest, or may be roll forward to the right if the surface was not leveled (assuming we had a way to prevent the bowling ball from rolling in the first place). so why is that?

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/Lesson-2/Momentum-Conservation-Principle

Comment: How are you applying this force to the bowling ball? Sounds like you are doing it yourself, therefore you are the one getting the equal and opposite reaction—not the beach ball. The beach ball will experience a frictional force from the now moving bowling ball, which explains why it moves in the same direction as the bowling ball, until it falls off shortly after.

Comment: You are probably confusing yourself by not understanding how rocket propulsion works. A really fundamental way to think about it is little bombs at rest in your thruster. At t=-1 they are at rest, and at t=0 they explode into two perfect halves. Half of the shell leaves your thruster, and the other half slams into your ship, pushing it forward. This is more how these things work, harnessing chemical energy to create these explosions. Another method is thinking about throwing balls while standing on a 4 wheel floor scooter. You throw them backwards, you move forward, conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's Third Law of Motion applies between two bodies: if body A applies a force on body B, then body B applies an equal, but opposite force upon body A.

Let the upper ball be A, and the lower ball B. Gravity supplies a force on A, which can be found using Newton's 2nd Law of Motion and the local gravitational acceleration, F=mg; this force passes from A to B, through the surface contact. This force is thus $ FA=m_A×g$.

By Newton's 3rd law, the reaction force is $ FB =-FA $. This is the normal force.

Now you introduce a new force, by pulling the bottom ball away. Call this the grabbing force on B, $ GFB $. The friction between the two balls is proportional to the normal force between them, so as you pull the lower ball away, the frictional force will oppose the motion of your ball, B; and the reaction force, acting on A, will be equal and opposite. It will cause the now falling A to begin rotaing as it falls.

Comment: Careful, here.  The force of A on B is also a normal force, not a gravitational force.  Your language is a bit loose.   Ball A has two forces on it:  gravity (down) and normal due to B (up).  Ball B has three forces on it:  gravity (down), normal due to A (down) and normal due to the floor (up).

Comment: @garyp: I think that's exactly what I said, but with more words. I'm trying to help him learn to analyze these problems, as opposed to solving this particular one .

Comment: My concern is the phrase "Gravity supplies a force from A to B."  I understand that you do go on to explain about contact, but a quick read will focus on the first phrase.  Then you pose the equation $FA = m_Ag$ without explaining that the origin of that result is a combination of Newton's third and second laws.    Like I said:  loose language.  I know what you were trying to say, but I think it is a bit too sloppy to present to a novice.

Comment: @garyp: agreed; I updated the text.